# Как спарсить значение атрибута через xpath в anglesharp?

Tags: c#, html, xpath, anglesharp

Как спарсить значение атрибута через xpath в anglesharp ?
Беру пример из другого [вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21455349/xpath-query-get-attribute-href-from-a-tag) и немного меняю HTML что бы подошел мой xpath.

```
//div[@class='g']/div/div/a/@href
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div class ='g'>
    <div>
      <div>
  <a href="http://www.example.com">Example</a>
  <a href="http://www.stackoverflow.com">SO</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Тестирую через сайт для онлайн теста и через плагин в chrome. Получаю то что и хотел получить а именно значение атрибута **href**

Я хочу спарсить ссылки с выдачи гугла. Вот что показывает xpath в chrome
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но когда я использую этот  xpath в AngleSharp.XPath все работает не так.
Вот мой код

```C#
var document = await context.OpenAsync(address);
            System.Collections.Generic.List<AngleSharp.Dom.INode> lists = null;

            try {
                lists = document.Body.SelectNodes("//div[@class='g']/div/div/a/@href");
                
            }
            catch (Exception ex) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }

            foreach (var f in lists) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine(f.TextContent);
            
            }
```

Вот что я получаю в f.TextContent
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

У f. есть поле f.Href в нем лежит значение атрибута href но я не могу к нему обратится.

Comment: А вы смотрели тот HTML, который пытаетесь спарсить? Пока выглядит, что вы смотрите данные в одном месте, а проблему решаете в другом. `f.GetAttribute("href")` пробовали?

Comment: Такова метода нет.

Comment: Тогда так попробуйте `foreach (IHtmlAnchorElement f in lists)`, сможете обратиться к `f.Href`.

Comment: Тоже самое выводит(

Comment: https://pastebin.com/u4e3hHcF вот полностью код

Comment: Вы наверное решили пошутить, а я шутки не понял, простите `Console.WriteLine(f.Href)`

Comment: Я же говорю что нет такова поля.
Ошибка CS1061 "INode" не содержит определения "Href", и не удалось найти доступный метод расширения "Href", принимающий тип "INode" в качестве первого аргумента (возможно, пропущена директива using или ссылка на сборку). testmal3

Comment: А если так? `foreach (IHtmlLinkElement f in lists) Console.WriteLine(f.Href);`

Comment: А так вылетает эксепшен Unable to cast object of type 'AngleSharp.Html.Dom.HtmlAnchorElement' to type 'AngleSharp.Html.Dom.IHtmlLinkElement'.

Comment: Тег a, это IHtmlAnchorElement

Comment: Ну вот в ошибке вам и написало тип, я просто не знаю AngleSharp.XPath, мне кажется юзать XPath в фреймворке, где есть QuerySelector, весьма сомнительное занятие. `foreach (HtmlAnchorElement f in lists) Console.WriteLine(f.Href);` без `I`.

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Comment: Оформите ответом пожалуйста, я отмечу и плюсану.